# What's the best practice for maintaining an aggregate value in the parent of a has_many relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

A pretty common pattern is to have an attribute in the parent model of an association be some summary/aggregate value from the children, for example, a total or an average or some such thing.  The typical:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items
  # total_cost
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
  # cost
end
```

and every time an `Item` is added or removed, you want `total_cost` in the parent to be updated.  It's also possible, of course, that the cost of an `Item` might change, in which case the `total_cost` would also need to be updated.

I haven't been able to find a really good guide to best practice, and I've seen it done many different ways.

The basic question, I guess, is who should be responsible for maintaining the `total_cost` value?  It seems to me it really needs to be the `Item` (unless `Items` are immutable once they've been associated with the parent).

Is the best way just to have `after_save` and `after_destroy` callbacks on the `Item` which call a method in the `Order` which updates its `total_cost`?

Comment: can i expect some response from you ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you have to save total_cost in your DB and make it updated then the best way is to have `after_save` and `after_destroy` callbacks on the Item which will update Order's total_cost.

By the way, you can also calculate the `total_cost` by defining a method in the Order model without saving it at Database.Like the following

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items

 def total_cost
    return self.items.sum(:cost)
 end
end
```

In this way you don't need any callbacks.you can access this as a field in Order model.and also you don't need to worry about item update delete or new item added.You also don't have to save this in DB table.

Comment: Sure, you don't have to store the values and can calculate them on the fly as needed.  But if your application is going to scale, you probably want to consider the [N+1 queries problem](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations) or you may want to denormalize for easier reporting.